# Visual Studio 2017: how to include NuGet packages in solution folder

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

To date, using Visual Studio 2015, NuGet packagas are restored into a solution-specific "packages" folder, which I check in to source control.  Our TFS Build server does not have Internet access, so it needs these local copies to successfully build.

I am now trying out Visual Studio 2017, with a .NETStandard Class library, and it no longer makes a local copy of NuGet packages - instead they appear to be stored in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%.nuget\packages.  This means they are no longer available on the Build server.

How can I get NuGet to store packages locally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to define a [RestorePackagesPath property](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-NuGet-settings-in-MSBuild#project-properties) in your .NET Standard (SDK style) project which defines where the NuGet packages should be restored to.

You can use this to tell NuGet to not use the .nuget\packages directory but instead use some other directory relative to your project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RestorePackagesPath>..\path\to\MyPackages</RestorePackagesPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Looking at the [NuGet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#forcing-restore-from-package-sources) they mention three possible approaches when using a project that uses PackageReferences.

1. Set the NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable to a different folder.
2. Create a NuGet.Config file that sets globalPackagesFolder to a different folder.
3. Specify a different folder with the RestorePackagesPath MSBuild property.

Comment: I went for a NuGet.config file in the solution directory, so that all projects in the solution use the same folder.  Previously I'd tried this unsuccessfully, because I used key="repositoryPath", whereas a PackageReference requires key="globalPackagesFolder" - though I think globalPackagesFolder is an unintuitive name for a solution-specific folder.